# How to grab a part of existing URL and use it in html code?

Tags: php

From the URL, let's say google.com/web1.php I would like to grab the part between the last slash and the extension, so: "web1" and then use it to point the specific image. Here is the example:

for url: google.com/web1.php

```
<img src="web1.jpg">
```

for url: google.com/web2.php

```
<img src="web2.jpg">
```

I know how to insert the whole URL, but don't know how to get a part of it. Here is what I use for the whole URL:

```
<img src="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>.jpg"/>
```

How to get only the part I want instead of the whole URL?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print just:

```
echo  $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

It will print only the part you need.

Usually, the URI of a URL does not have the extension. In your case need to parse it.

```
echo preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
```

If you want to add the code on each php file, you could do this:

```
 echo pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: will it contain only the filename without the extension or domain name too? I need just a filename, as I will name .jpg's the same way as websites and will need to have a different jpg on each of pages.

Comment: Yes, that code only will have that. also if you have many PHP files, on each file you could make this: (see updated post)

Comment: Almost perfect, the only thing that needs tweaking is the last slash at the end. Currently it looks like this: <img src="web1/.jpg"> Can you help me get rid of the slash after the grabbed part? Thank you

Comment: echo pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);